# Heteroskedasticity Adjusted Correlation Coefficients

Tags: correlation, heteroscedasticity, finance

I've been reading Forbes & Rigobon (2002) "[No contagion, only interdependence](https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w7267/w7267.pdf)" article, in which they suggest to adjust the correlation coefficients for heteroskedasticity.

I can't figure out the steps to measure the adjusted correlation coefficients however. They provide this equation for the adjusted correlation coefficient ($\rho_t$) :

$\rho_t=\frac{\rho^u_t}{\sqrt{1+\delta_t(1-\rho^u_t)^2}}$

where $\rho^u$ is the unadjusted (biased) correlation coefficient, and $\delta_t = \frac{\sigma^h_{xx}}{\sigma^l_{xx}}-1$

$\sigma$ being the variance, $x$ the return of an asset. They divide the variance of $x_t$ into two sets so that the variance of $x_t$ is high in one group  $h$ and low in the other $l$.

*(there may be some missing informations, I can provide them if needed though I don't think that I can figure which informations are important in the paper)*

From a practical point of view, how could I (within R program possibly) measure this unconditional correlation coefficient ?